# Should we reduce the use of [reducers]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

In a general sense, a reducer is a function that takes a set of data and reduces it to a new value.

There are multiple common use cases for reducers.  The current tag description for the [reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) tag describes only one of these uses:

> Refers to reducers in the mapreduce framework. Mappers split up a large problem and solve parts of it in parallel. Reducers collect and summarize the output of a map method.

The majority of the questions refer to other uses.  Is the usage wrong or is the wiki wrong?

You could make an argument that the [reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) tag doesn't add anything to questions which are already tagged with a specific tag like [mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapreduce). Or you could make the counter argument that the concepts of reducers, dispatch, and selectors for state management are independent of the specific implementations of [@ngrx/store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#writing-reducers), and React's built-in [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook.

---

Pairings:

- [clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [18 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clojure+reducers)
- [hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [144 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers+hadoop)
- [mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapreduce)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [107 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mapreduce+reducers)
- [ngrx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngrx)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [29 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngrx+reducers)
- [ngrx-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngrx-store)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [11 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngrx-store+reducers)
- [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [386 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs+reducers)
- [react-redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-redux)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [155 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-redux+reducers)
- [redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux)[reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers) [397 Qs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux+reducers)

[66 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reducers%2B-mapreduce%2B-reactjs%2B-redux%2B-ngrx%2B-react-redux%2B-ngrx-store%2B-hadoop%2B-clojure?tab=newest&page=1&pagesize=15) out of the 793 total have none of the above tags.

Related Tags:

- [array-reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-reduce) 34 Qs
- [use-reducer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use-reducer) 211 Qs
- [redux-reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redux-reducers) 94 Qs
- [ngrx-reducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngrx-reducers) 24 Qs
- [reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reduce) 2701 Qs

##### Edit:

There appears to be a consensus around [Jared Smith's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407912/10431574) that the wiki should be updated to reflect the broader concept of a reducer.  Can anyone take a stab at rewriting it?

Comment: React definitely has the lion's share of usage for this tag; at least [644 of the 793](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breducers%5D+AND+%5B*react*%5D) Q's (that's ~81%) are tagged with a [\*react\*] tag.

Comment: [755 of 793](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Breducers%5D+AND+%5B*react*%5D+OR+%5B*redux*%5D) if you include [\*redux\*]

Comment: The wiki seems like it's not specific enough - whilst I'm 99% sure it wasn't 'invented' by redux, that's where the majority of developers who use the term would have heard about it

Answer (score 20):

The wiki is wrong.

If MapReduce even needs a specific tag, then the tag needs to be specific, something like `mapreduce-reducers`. Reducers are an abstract concept (I hesitate to use the semantically-overloaded term "design pattern") that show up pretty often in several kinds of development.

As pointed out by your analysis, React/Redux (Javascript) and Clojure transducers make heavy use of the concept, limiting a tag with a generic name to a specific thing seems out-of-line with the way the rest of the tagging system works.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  This was my gut instinct as well — that the wiki is wrong and should be updated to reflect the broader concept of a reducer.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thank you for bringing attention to it!